# trying to replicte css grid image gallery from youtube but got stuck

Tags: html, css, grid

[![desired result
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx0xP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx0xP.jpg)

[![current result(note: image was too big to post here but just imagine all of the columned images running to the bottom of the window

```css
.wrapper {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
 grid-auto-rows: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CSS Grid</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vertical"><img src="img/p1.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="horizontal"><img src="img/p15.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="" alt=""><img src="p2.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="vertical"><img src="img/p14.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="img/p3.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="img/p4.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="horizontal"><img src="img/p7.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="img/p8.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="vertical"><img src="img/p9.jpeg" alt=""></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> my codes the same as the guys is in the video, in fact everything was easy as can be till i got here. heres a link to the video-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6CBKf8K_Ac&t=1952s. I'm at 29:55

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcX4w.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcX4w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if the video mentions it, but adding...

```
img{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   object-fit:cover;
}
```

... to your images all become similar to your desired result!

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 75px;
}
img{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="vertical"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div class="horizontal"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div class="vertical"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div class="horizontal"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
    <div class="vertical"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/75" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i added it but nothing happened?

Comment: In my snippet all works well. I used your HTML. Are you using Explorer?